# live streaming using red5

Tags: php, flash, video-streaming, red5

I installed *red5* server on my *Ubuntu 12.04 server*. It is up and running.

I am trying to do live streaming. I set up *rtmp* protocol as well. Port 1935 is listening for red5.

I installed midiDemo app and I started my flash media encoder to start streaming. When I go to demo apps publisher.html I can see my streaming which means that rtmp is working.

I tried couple of players on my site to stream and they work just when flash media encoder is streaming. How can I stream on my site without flash media encoder? Also I want, when user comes to site to have option to start and stop streaming. My web site is php.

Comment: The midi app seems an odd choice for this, even though it will work fine. Depending upon the red5 version, you could use the live, vod, or oflaDemo apps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the publisher app to "publish", similar to using FMLE. One difference is that the only audio and video codecs available in that demo app are Sorenson video and NellyMoser audio.

Comment: I have tried doing this with oflaDemo app and i have a problem with rtmp link when i try to connect                                           rtmp://mysite/oflaDemo                                                                                    i get No scope 'oflaDemo' on this server, while with midiDemo works fine. I did put oflaDemo war into olfaDemo folder in webapps folder. Live and vod i haven’t try. Overall after installation and setting up Red5 server I am missing the part how to make live stream on my site. I am not sure which technologies i need to use to implement all that.

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to use the html test bed where  you can setup streaming and view the results by running one of several demos provided. Download the html5 sdk. The link below will show you how:

https://www.red5pro.com/docs/server/

Download the Red5 Pro WebRTC SDK to use the sample streaming apps. Download here:

https://www.red5pro.com/docs/client/webrtc/